# What is the quality of the Ryoji Matsuoka M30 Classical Guitar

Tags: guitar, instruments, classical-guitar

I am curious about Ryoji Matsuoka classical guitars, particularly the M30 model. Is this make intended for beginners, intermediate players, or professionals? Are there any known unique qualities or shortcomings of these guitars?

Comment: The original question was clearly a shopping question, but I think this is interesting so I've rewritten in a way that is answerable and should provide you with most of the same information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A Ryoji Matsuoka of course, for intermediate to advanced users. They're known to be  finest handcrafted classical guitar in Japan (also Yamaha, Kodaira, Aranjuez, Asturias, Shunpei Nishino and more). Matsuoka himself produce some guitars in 70-80s in a small workshop (which he doesn't build the guitar alone).

For the tone, and sounds, you can check my friend's playing [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=130398833706239&set=vb.100002083700267&type=3) with Matsuoka M30 or [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=130453827034073&set=vb.100002083700267&type=3) with Shunpei Nishino No. 15. Same person, same song.